# Merge 2 arrays with refernce to key and add thier values using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to merge multiple arrays with same keys and add their values if keys exist, if not add a new object. Could not get the logic right on this

these are samle arrays

```
[{"2":"90"},{"12":"400"},{"25":"750"},{"0":"50"}] 
[{"1":"100"},{"23":"200"},{"12":"1000"},{"0":"5"}]
```

and the expected output is

```
[{ {"2":"90"},{"12":"1400"},{"25":"750"},{"0":"55"},{"1":"100"},{"23":"200"}]
```

This is php code i have used

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
      {
          
             if ($i==0)
             {
                 $rowOut = $row;
                 $i++;
             }else
             {
                    foreach($rowOut as $key1 => $value1) {
                        
                        foreach($row as $key => $value) 
                        {
                        
                            if($key == $key1){
                                
                                 (int)$rowOut->$value1 = (int)$value + (int)$value1;
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }  
             }
         
        }
```

Comment: what language is it [{"2":"90"},{"12":"400"},{"25":"750"},{"0":"50"}] ??

Comment: This code is full of errors. `$i` is not defined so you're always straight into the `else{}` part. There `$rowOut` is not defined (because you never get to the `if(...)` part), should give an error. If that is fixed, you're looping `$row` again, but that is the result of `$result->fetch_assoc()`. Start by looping your resultset and making some decent arrays.

Comment: @WiatroBosy, to be curious, what kind of thing you think of rather than json? It is quite obvious for me is JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

not the most elegant solution, but it works

```
$a = [2=>90,12=>400,25=>750,0=>50] ;
$b = [1=>100,23=>200,12=>1000,0=>5];
$ak = array_keys($a);
$bk = array_keys($b);
$ck = array_intersect($ak,$bk);
$out = [];
foreach ($ck as $key => $value)
{
    $out[$value] = $a[$value] + $b[$value];
    unset($a[$value]);
    unset($b[$value]);
}

foreach ($a as $key => $value)
{
    $out[$key] = $value;
}

foreach ($b as $key => $value)
{
    $out[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may concat the two arrays and use reduce to construct the new array.

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e03d2c1ed12e75aaf16b89a60d2048acaec4da60)

```php
<?php
$array1 = [
    ["2" => "90"],
    ["12" => "400"],
    ["25" => "750"],
    ["0" => "50"]
];

$array2 = [
    ["1" => "100"],
    ["23" => "200"],
    ["12" => "1000"],
    ["0" => "5"]
];

$concat = [...$array1, ...$array2];

$reduce = array_reduce($concat, function ($carry, $item) {
    $key = array_keys($item)[0];

    if (isset($carry[$key])) {
        $carry[$key][$key] += $item[$key];
    } else {
        $carry[$key] = [$key => $item[$key]];
    }
    $carry[$key][$key] = (string)$carry[$key][$key];
    return $carry;
}, []);

$output = array_values($reduce);

echo var_dump($output);
```